# How to replace \xA0 characters in an NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, unicode, nsstring

The following code doesn't work:

```
NSString *importText = [textView.string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\xA0\xA0"
 withString:@" "];
```

Compiler claims: 
"Input conversion stopped due to an input byte that don't belong to the input code set UTF8"

Comment: what's the content of textView.string?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Unicode escape sequence `\u00a0`.