# How to replace occurrence of \xa0 character in NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsstring

I have already looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643955/how-to-replace-xa0-characters-in-an-nsstring) but there was no solution.
Here is the problem.

```
po [myNumberFormatter stringFromNumber:myNumber]
```

Output--> (id) $4 = 1.500,00

```
p (char) [(NSString *)[myNumberFormatter stringFromNumber:myNumber] characterAtIndex:1]
```

Output--> (char) $5 = '\xa0'

```
po [(NSString *)[myNumberFormatter stringFromNumber:myNumber] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\xa0" withString:@" "]
```

Output--> (id) $6 = 1.500,00

One thing to note though is that on the screen, the value **1.500,00** looks like **1 500,00**.
But is there any way to convert the '\xa0' character to a @" " within the string?

This following solution already works, but it has the problem of converting everything not included into a blank character.

```
po [(NSString *)[myNumberFormatter stringFromNumber:myNumber] stringByReplacingSequenceOfCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)[[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789,."] invertedSet] with:@" "]
```

**Edit** --------------

I've tried the answer below and i thought it was wrong becuase

```
po [(NSString *)[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:theNumber] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u00a0" withString:@" "]
```

still produced the same result (the \xa0 char was still not removed).  But when I did not place it in the debugger, but instead placed it in a NSString within the code, the correct answer was stored and the \xa0 character was removed. Guess I should not depend on debugger log alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSString *str = // string to cleanup
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\u00a0" withString:@" "];
```

The \u00a0 will get replaced at compile time with an actual no-break space.

Comment: I have tried @"\u00a0" but this does not work. any other suggestion? i can show you the whole code if needed.

Comment: I do this in my own code and it works fine. You could try replacing the \u00a0 with an actual non-break space in your code. From the Edit menu, select Special Characters. Go to the 00a0 character and insert into your code.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion replacing "\u00a0" is not a generic solution because there are chances that nect time server may send any other unicode character then the code will not be able to handle that. Also "\u00a0" isnot a string its a character.PFB the code that i used to filter out only digits from server response that was:

```
phoneNumber= "000 \U00a0950";
```

Since i just wanted numbers in phoneNumber i wrote:

```
self.phoneNumber = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[[_storeDetails objectForKey "phone"] length]]; //which  is 000 \U00a0950

NSCharacterSet *numberCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]; 

 for (int i = 0; i < [[_storeDetails objectForKey "phone"] length]; i++)
 { 
 unichar characterOfPhoneNumber = [[_store objectForKey "phone"] characterAtIndex:i]; 
   if ([numberCharacterSet characterIsMember:characterOfPhoneNumber]) 
   { [self.phoneNumber appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat "%c",characterOfPhoneNumber]];
 } 
}
```

//in the above code i parsed each character and checked if that was a number, added that in an array and hence the array is unicode free.
PS:\U00a0 is a character