# How to display all rows of a DataFrame based on a condition that a specific column strings are blank?

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, formatting

I'm experiencing difficulties displaying rows of the dataframe.

The thing is I want to display all rows of the DataFrame with a condition that strings of one specific column are blank.

If I try `df.loc[df.column == '']` or `df.loc[df.column == None]` I get nothing.

Here's the link to my Github page where you find 2 files: **module_2.ipynb** and **cacao_flavors.csv** which is a DataFrame I use. (https://github.com/drlivesey85/projects.git)

I need to get all rows where company is blank.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Please find updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do have some strange encoding in the example dataframe (which I don't know what it is referring about). Maybe some symbol that seems to be encoded in some MAC code. Anyway, if you set your statement with that in mind, you can actually get the rows you're looking for.
Here's my solution:

```
cacao.loc[cacao[column]=='\xa0', :]
```

EDIT:
here you can find a way to replace it: [How to replace \xA0 characters in an NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643955/how-to-replace-xa0-characters-in-an-nsstring?rq=1)
Note that the code works properly with that change too: `cacao.loc[cacao[column]=='\u00a0', :]`

Comment: el_Rinaldo, Thanks! It does work! I couldn't even thought of such a thing as this.. 

Different kind of spaces, hu?  Is there any articles on this topic I could read? I first thought it's a regular expression you use.

By the way, what if I use this code to turn all these 'blanks' into 'Nones'? :

 ```cacao.company = cacao.company.apply(lambda x: None if x.strip() == '' else x)```

Will it help me to make my way easier?

Comment: Well, have you already took a look at this discussion? Maybe it can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25530142/list-of-pandas-read-csv-encoding-list.
For your second question, consider to try something like this: `cacao.company.apply(lambda x: None if x == '\xa0' else x)`

Comment: Thanks again for your immense help! I will go thru the links you shared.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
cacao.loc[cacao.company.isna(),]
```

Also, you should refer to [this page](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), it helps others to provide quick responses.

Comment: SAL, Thanks for your help but still it doesn't work.. ‍♀️